# Firebase linking anon UID to email verification if verified on a different device

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Has anyone managed to associate an authorised email to an anon UID that was created earlier on another device?

Here is the workflow:

1. User comes to the site for the first time, anon UID is created, they enter email as part of signup, which is added to their details in the db
2. An email is sent to them to verify the email.
3. However, user misses it for whatever reason.
4. Instead, they come again with a different device and try to log in using a password-less login by entering their email and receiving a link
5. they get the link and click on it. The email gets verified, but gets assigned to a NEW UID created on the 2nd visit.

The question is how can the email be linked to the 1st UID instead of the 2nd one on a new device?

Under 2, before the email is sent, I am calling firebase.auth().currentUser.updateEmail(email), but it doesn't seem to associate the email with the UID in the firebase for some reason. I can see that in the Firebase Authentication tab -- the UID is still showing as Identifier (anonymous). This is probably the root cause of the issue as otherwise the email would be there, just unauthenticated.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Setting an email address to an anonymous account doesn't change its provider to suddenly become email+password. It remains an anonymous account, it now just also has an email address associated with it. To associate the user with an email+password account, you'll have to sign them in with email+password credentials and then link those credentials to the existing anonymous account.

To link accounts/providers, you must create credentials for both providers on the same device and call the relevant API to link them.

Since you only have a UID from anonymous sign-in on the first device, that UID can't be recreated on the second device. And that means there is no way to link the email-link UID account on the second device to the anonymous UID on the first device.

Comment: So what's Firebase's recommended way of dealing with the scenario described above?

Comment: To associate an anon account with an email one - perhaps creating a passwordless account once the user provides their email? Will this converting their anon account into an email-associated account at that point even without the user actually clicking on the verification link?

Comment: No it doesn't. I recommend following the steps to [link email address and password credentials to an existing user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account).